# if $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence functions measurable is $d-$Cauchy then is Cauchy measure.

Tags: measure-theory, cauchy-sequences

Let $([0,1], \mathscr{B}([0,1]), \lambda)$ measure space. If $f,g \in M([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]))$ we define the pseudometric $$d(f,g)= \int_{0}^{1}\min\{|f(x)-g(x)|,1\}d\lambda$$

Prove if $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence functions measurable is $d-$Cauchy then is Cauchy measure. *Note: $d-$ Cauchy means, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n,m \geq N$ then $d(f_n,f_m)<\epsilon$

We know that $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is $d-$Cauchy, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\mu(\{x \in [0,1]: d(f_n(x),f_m(x)) \geq \epsilon \})=0$ but just I have $$\{x \in [0,1]: d(f_n(x),f_m(x)) \geq \epsilon \} \subset \{x \in [0,1]: |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \geq \epsilon \}$$ So, do you know other relation with that sets or other form to get the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0<\varepsilon <1$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}\lambda(|f_n-f_m|>\varepsilon)&=\int_{\{\varepsilon<|f_n-f_m|< 1\}}d\lambda + \int_{\{|f_n-f_m|\geq  1\}}d\lambda=\\
&= \varepsilon^{-1}\int_{\{\varepsilon<|f_n-f_m|< 1\}}\varepsilon d\lambda + \int_{\{|f_n-f_m|\geq  1\}}\min(|f_n-f_m|,1)d\lambda\leq \\
&\leq \varepsilon^{-1}\int_{\{\varepsilon<|f_n-f_m|< 1\}}\min(|f_n-f_m|,1)d\lambda + \int_{\{|f_n-f_m|\geq  1\}}\min(|f_n-f_m|,1)d\lambda\leq\\
&\leq (1+\varepsilon^{-1})\int_{[0,1]}\min(|f_n-f_m|,1)d\lambda
\end{aligned}$$
Let $\varepsilon \geq 1$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}\lambda(|f_n-f_m|>\varepsilon)&=\int_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\varepsilon\}}d\lambda=\\
&=\int_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\varepsilon\}}\min(|f_n-f_m|,1)d\lambda\leq\\
&\leq \int_{[0,1]}\min(|f_n-f_m|,1)d\lambda
\end{aligned}$$